# SQL Query Simples

Tags: sql

Estou iniciando com Banco de Dados, e me deparei com uma situação que simplesmente não estou entendendo.

Eu queria pegar o nome do aluno e o nome da materia que estão na tabela 3 no caso "`TbMateriasAluno`"

Usei esse comando Select mas não deu certo

```
Select TbAluno.NomeAluno , TbMaterias from TbAluno Inner Join 
 TbMateriasAluno On TbMateriasAluno.ID_Aluno = TbAluno.NomeAluo
```

Tenho 3 Tabelas.

Tabela TbAluno:

```
|---TbAluno---|

 *ID

 *NomeAluno

|--------------
```

Tabela TbMaterias:

```
|---TbMaterias ---|

*ID

*NomeMateria

|--------------
```

e a tabela TbMateriasAluno

```
|---TbMateriasAluno---|

 *ID

 *ID_Aluno

 *ID_Materia

|--------------
```

Comment: Olha quase `TbAluno.NomeAluo` para **TbAluno.NomeAluno** e ai deu certo? e veja tutorial mais facilidade http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-joins-em-sql/1071

Comment: KingRider não deu certo não eu até consigo pegar um ou outro, Consigo pegar o nome do aluno mas não consigo pegar o nome da matéria. Será que você poderia me passar essa query para eu estudar?

Comment: Hum, aqui rodou certinho e não entendi seu erro, qual se esta utilizando oracle? mssql? mysql? isso depende a linguagem funcionar sql diferenciado, e mas veja o allan andrade postou é achei pouca diferença. Deu certo dele?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com o seu modelo de dados, entendo que você deveria efetuar o join entre as 3 tabelas para chegar no resultado desejado :

```
Select 
   NomeAluno, TbMaterias.NomeMateria
From 
   TbAluno
   INNER Join TbMateriasAluno On ( TbAluno.ID = TbMateriasAluno.ID_Aluno )
   Inner Join TbMaterias On ( TbMateriasAluno.ID_Materia = TbMaterias.ID )
```

**Query adaptada para rodar no Access** 
Perceba que é necessário incluir parênteses, para que esse banco de dados entenda a relação entre as tabelas:

```
Select 
   NomeAluno, TbMaterias.NomeMateria
From 
   ( TbAluno
   INNER Join TbMateriasAluno On  TbAluno.ID = TbMateriasAluno.ID_Aluno  )
   Inner Join TbMaterias On ( TbMateriasAluno.ID_Materia = TbMaterias.ID )
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Eric Roberto Era exatamente esse o erro, Se não for pedir muito qual o sentido desses parênteses não conseguir enxergar como eles estão sendo usados. Mesmo assim Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte `query`:

```
select 
  a.NomeAluno
  , m.NomeMateria
from TbAluno as a
left join TbMateriasAluno as ma on ma.ID_Aluno = a.id
left join TbMaterias as m on m.id = ma.ID_Materia
```

Veja [**este exemplo funcionando** no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0179/1).

Comment: Muito Obrigado Allan Pelo Exemplo, è Como falei lá em cima, está dendo erro de sintaxe deve ser coisa do meu banco " Acess " Mas vlws mesmo